# Data is not loading in UITableView. What could be the issue?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, tableview, segue

I have a `UITableView` in next segue when a button is pressed. The code that i have implemented in the implementation file is as follows. The view is shifting, but the data is not loading in the view.

What could be the problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];
        NSError* error;
        tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: did you set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of you tableView?

Comment: Have you checked that you are receiving proper JSON? NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);

Comment: yes, delegate and dataSource both are set to tableview

Comment: In another sample project, the same code is working absolutely fine. So i am assuming that the JSON received is proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}
```

**Don't you need at least 1 section?**

Comment: I might need later on. But for now, it's just for the testing purpose.

Comment: @MonisManzoor Anthony is quite right - zero sections are not enough, you **do need** one.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This seems to work a bit. But still the data is not loading into the tableview. It now shows "by null" in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should use breakpoints in the debugger to break on the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to verify that your data is being parsed and handled correctly. If you're unfamiliar with breakpoints now is a good chance to get to know them - they are *invaluable* in debugging and resolving problems.

As a general note, you probably shouldn't be using `dataWithContentsOfURL` to do your networking. It's not really designed for that usage. `NSURLConnection` is a much better option, which will give you far more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
dyspatch_async
```

is named is as because  it's asynchronous. You seem to be thinking that the second call to it is executed after the first call - but no. They're executes parallel, and because the URL operation is slower, the table view's update occurs when there's no data yet.

Solution: put the reloadData call in the same block as the URL operation - you don't need two separate calls to dispatch_async.

Also, you return 0 from

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView:
```

so the table doesn't even look for data. Return 1.

Comment: So why'd you revoked the +1? Did you see something wrong with my answer?

Comment: I didn't revoke anything. Both  the answer are apt from my perspective.